# Data not returning on http post request ionic

Tags: ionic4, ionic-http

I tried to fetch  auth-token from ionic-storage  and go for a post request with that token, but HTTP post is not returning anything

this is my implementation

````
GET_Communities() {
return(this.storage.ready().then(
     () => {
       this.storage.get(TOKEN_KEY).then(
         (token) => {

    console.log(token);
    return(this.http.post('https://example.com/api/communities', JSON.stringify(token)).pipe(

    ) );
  }
  );

}```
````

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what is the plugin you use for http but you should try this native plugin :

```js
import { HTTP } from '@ionic-native/http';
```

instead of

```js
import { HTTP } from '@angular/common/http';
```

if you use the last one

In ionic 4, you will have to do something like :

```js
import { http } from '@ionic-native/http';

this.http.post('https://example.com/api/communities', JSON.stringify(token)', {})
  .pipe(

  )
```

Learn more about it here : https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/native/http/